# alter table change Default value zero in mysql community server

Tags: mysql

I have been using Mysql community server now i want to alter a column null to zero while creating i have using this code

```
ALTER TABLE student_data CHANGE COLUMN is_status is_status int(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
```

but this code works only in mysql not in mysql community server rows are not get afftecting  what to do to alter a  column value null to zero

Comment: The Default value is only used for new rows, not for existing rows. Also what is the issue and how your insert Statements Looks like

Comment: How exactly is it not working? As far as I know you cannot have a `NOT NULL` column with `NULL` value, not even in MySQL. Oracle does not mangle the community edition this way :-?

Comment: An alter statement changes the structure of a table not the content. You need an update statement to change the content.

Comment: s i havent updated nw its working